# Handling backslash when parsing json

Tags: javascript, json

Here is a portion of a larger JSON string that I attempting to call JSON.parse on.  I am getting the infamous 'invalid character' error because (I believe) of the backslash parentheses *(ie. "path:\"https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/Test\")*.

All online parsers I have tried it on works fine but in my javascript code the JSON.parse method fails.

I have attempted to clean the string like this and other ways but I have been unable to get it to parse.

```
var cleanData = data.replace(/\\"/, /\\\\/);
```

below is the partial JSON file.  When I remove it from the JSON string the JSON.parse works so I think I have this isolated to just this.  What type of general purpose clean method would work to get this thing to parse?  Thansk

```
'{"Properties" : {
    "GenerationId" : 9223372036854776000,
    "indexSystem" : "",
    "ExecutionTimeMs" : 109,
    "QueryModification" : "path:\"https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/Test\"  (IsDocument:\"True\" OR contentclass:\"STS_ListItem\") ContentTypeId:0x0120D5200098CBB075E51C8C4398ECCB4B4928912D*",
    "RenderTemplateId" : "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Group_Default.js",
    "StartRecord" : 0,
    "piPageImpressionBlockType" : 2
}}
```

how?

Comment: How does the JSON content get passed to the JavaScript? Embedded in the page by a server-side script? Ajax request?

Comment: Yes it is a string property on the SharePoint context object called ctx.  The ctx is available to Javascript client.

Comment: Can you show a bit more of an example of what you're trying to do? What JavaScript client are you referring to? What other technologies are being used here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your backslash is getting swallowed as an escape character in the string:

```
'\"' === '"' // true
```

You actually need to escape the backslashes, so that the JSON parser sees them. Here's another example:

```
var unencoded = 'string with "quotes"';

'"string with \"quotes\""'   === JSON.stringify(unencoded); // false
'"string with \\"quotes\\""' === JSON.stringify(unencoded); // true
```

However, where the escaping should be done depends on how the JSON is being made available to the JavaScript. If the JSON is embedded in the page by a server-side script, then there's no need to use `JSON.parse`, as valid JSON is valid JavaScript:

```
// if JsonData is valid JSON, it's also a valid JavaScript object
var data = <%= JsonData %>;
```

Comment: On the live system i get it like this. ctx.ListData.ResultTables.  I am capturing this JSON as a string so I can write code on a test web page using this JSON.stringify(ctx.ListData.ResultTables)

Comment: The ResultTables is an json object

Comment: So is `ctx` a JavaScript object? Why are you stringifying it and then parsing it again? What's the ultimate goal?

Comment: I am doing that because i want to use that json file to write code on a development page. It is faster for writing and testing code

Comment: OK, so how do you write the code on the development page? You should just need to do something like `var data = <%= JsonData %>;`

Comment: Yeah that is it.  var data = "big json string"

Comment: then JSON.parse(data)

Comment: i am trying clean up data prior to parsing because the backslash is causing it to fail.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Don't wrap the JSON string in quotes, and it will work as expected.